# Append to ArrayList stored in external file

Tags: java, arrays, file

I have a file, called `ArrayList.data`, that stores an arraylist of hashmaps. Due to the constraints of the program I'm using, I cannot add all of my data at once, because the program creates a new instance for each user. To create an arraylist of all of the users' data, I need to open the file, add a user's data, and close the file.

The file only contains the arraylist of hashmaps. Is there a way to append to this hashmap each time, or do I need to keep replacing it with an updated, appended version?

Comment: When you say a file contains an arraylist...do you mean you Serialized it with an ObjectOutputStream?

Comment: There is a reason for the existence of databases, especially in-memory databases for your case. And then you could use JPA to "serialize" your entities.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Java serialization to store `ArrayList`? Unfortunately this mechanism won't allow you to incrementally add data to already serialized form. Instead, you would have to open the file, deserialize the whole `ArrayList`, add one element and serialize it back, overwriting the previous data in file. This approach is not feasible if list becomes big.

What you can do is serialize each `HashMap` (single `ArrayList<Map<?, ?>>` item) separately. This way when new item must be serialized, you simply open file and append this new `Map` in the end. When you want to deserialize it, just read each `Map` one after another and reconstruct the `ArrayList`.